# Finding the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

We are given two equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\sqrt{a}+b=11 \\
a+\sqrt{b}=7 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

How to find the value of $a$ and $b$ by solving the equation? All I could do was use the hit and trial method. Help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you already did, but I think it's easy enough to be a good method.

There aren't very many possibilities to try.  a & b must be non-negative because 7 and 11 are both real.  Also a & b must be perfect squares.  So from the 1st equation b<=9.  From the second a<=4.  So a could be 0, 1, 4.  a=0 and a=1 don't work by just plugging them in to the equations.  So a should be 4.  Which you can try and see that it works when b=9.

Comment: I have found a new way too. What if I suppose a as x^2 and b as y^2? Then, I wont have to worry about the square roots and the consequent difficulties that arise due to it.

Comment: I think that will get messy and will probably lead to 4th powers.  I didn't really try it out, but it's certainly a good avenue to investigate.  It's good that you're thinking of various ways to approach a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to work with squares than square roots, since we wind up with polynomial equations to solve.  Assuming $a,b \ge 0$ so square roots are real:

$$ a = (11 - b)^2 $$

$$ b = (7 - a)^2 $$

Substituting for $b$ in first equation from the second:

$$ a = (11 - (7-a)^2)^2 $$

gives a quartic equation to solve for (nonnegative) roots $a \in [0,7]$.

The polynomial equation turns out to be:

$$ a^4 - 28a^3 + 282a^2 - 1065a + 1444 = 0 $$

By [Rational Roots Thm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) any rational root would be an integer, and indeed there is an integer root in the desired range $[0,7]$.  Since such $a$ will divide $1444$, there aren't too many possibilities to check.

After you factor that root out, we're left with an irreducible cubic polynomial, and by [Descartes Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) it has at least one positive real root:

$$ a^3 - 24a^2 + 176a - 361 = 0 $$

one of which turns out to also be in the desired range, $a \approx 3.4156$.  However this gives a value for $b = (7-a)^2$ which is greater than $11$, $(7-a)^2 \approx 12.8479$.  In other words this is an "artifact" root created by the process of squaring both variables.

The only real solution of the original system of equations is $a=4,b=9$.